# Mask clipping in video editing Blender not working

Tags: video, masking

I want to make a mask in *Video Editing* on a video. I am told that I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>. The problem is that when I do this it doesn't work.

Nothing is displayed, the points to make the mask do not come.

How to fix this problem? I'm with version 3.3 of Blender.

Answer (score 0):

The default for blender 3.3 has the mask display unchecked for whatever reason. Located by the overlay menu.
[image: Mask Display location]
By clicking on the dropdown you can turn on both the spline (which will then display the points you're attempting to create) and the overlay. I recommend using combined so that you can see your mask settings over your render.
[image: Mask Display Settings]

I don't have much experience with the masking tool in video editing, but I found these two videos extremely important/helpful as I ran in to a couple other issues myself while setting up the mask for a video:

Applying the mask to your video edit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGjmNkjl5BM&ab_channel=MichaelChu

Explaining how to use masks (very generally): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix8tmIdLRZg&ab_channel=BlenderFrenzy

Hopefully this helps in some way!